# Warning: count() getting content of wordpress post in my single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i had try to get the content of wordpress posts in my single.php file, i got title and thumbnail , but when i use `the_content` in my code , a warning appear on the page.

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /home/altinaca/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 284

please  help me getting the content of the current post

```
<?php
    the_title();
    echo "<br>";
    the_post_thumbnail('full');
    echo "<br>";
    the_content();
 ?>
```

thank you so much

Comment: Maybe you are using jetpack older version.

Comment: no , i didnt use get_header and my wp_head function doesn't call any where of my application...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by plugins or themes calling `the_content()` outside of the Loop, where `$pages = null`. This will cause php 7.2 to throw an error if attempting to count non-countable types.

In your case you must put your `the_content()` function inside the main loop like this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) { the_post();

        the_title();
        echo "<br>";
        the_post_thumbnail('full');
        echo "<br>";
        the_content();

    }
}
```